# how can i enter Data in sheet 1 and transfer it into sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I would like enter information in sheet (data base type) have it go into Sheet 2 - locking the information in sheet 2 so when i enter data in sheet 1 again it populates in sheet 2 in the next row - is this possible?  like a data base ?

sheet 1 will be just for input purposes
Thank you 
PB

Comment: If you have to type it in sheet 1, why can't you just type it in sheet 2?

Comment: It is possible. Any other questions?

Comment: so you don't have to keep seeing the headers and its more user friendly

Comment: Bond yes the question is how can i do this,  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes... just have a button that send the information of this cell in Sheet1 to that cell in Sheet2, that cell having a defined column but a row equal to the next unused row. You can find the last unused row in A like so;

```
Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).row
```

Something like

```
Sub button
    dim nextrow as long
    nextrow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).row + 1
    Sheet2.Range("A" & nextrow) = Sheet1.Range("A1")
End sub
```

In this example, the information of sheet 1 cell A1 always go to the next available row in Sheet2, in column A. Hope this inspires you. (Code not tested).

Comment: Look into doing it on Worksheet_Change instead of having a button that needs to be clicked.

Comment: Will that automatically move the info. in Sheet2, A2 down to A3 when new info. is added to sheet1?

Comment: @BruceWayne No, as you can see it adds newer info to the bottom instead of bumping the old info down and writing the new up top. That's what he asked for in the question.

Comment: @DavidG - d'oh! Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a macro that will work any time someone changes what is in `Sheet1!B2`:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim entryWS As Worksheet, copyWS As Worksheet
Dim refRange As Range, copyRange As Range
Dim nextRow As Integer, startCol As Integer, endCol As Integer

'Since you want B:G let's say, for your entry data
startCol = 2
endCol = 7

Set entryWS = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set copyWS = Sheets("Sheet2")

With entryWS
Set refRange = .Range(.Cells(1, startCol), .Cells(1, endCol))
End With
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, refRange) Is Nothing Then 'If there's new info in your range
    Debug.Print "Working!"
    With copyWS
        nextRow = .Cells(1048576, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set copyRange = .Range(.Cells(nextRow, startCol), .Cells(nextRow, endCol))
    End With

    copyRange.Value = refRange.Value
End If


End Sub
```

Note: You must put this in a worksheet Object, not a module.  I placed this in "Sheet1".

This assumes that your `"Sheet1"` is where your input is.  Specifically, your user is inputting text into B1.  After you type into `Sheet1!B1`, it adds that text to `Sheet2`, moving the current list down one line.

edit: To enter this in a worksheet object, first right click your sheet, and go to "View Code":
[image]

Then, choose the sheet you're working in, and paste the data in the right side.  You can now run the macro (press the green play button along the top, or step through it by pressing `F8`):

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bruce, what if i have more inputs not just B1,  i would have like a form we can fill out with name:(b1) last name: (g1) and  maybe 10 more , i would then want those move to sheet2 in a particular order i have in the headers

Comment: Updated!  Note that since you want say B1:G1 for your entry range, i've set the start and end columns to `2` and `7`.  Change this as necessary for your Entry range.

Comment: Thank you Bruce, i am sorry my ignorance but how do i enter an object i went to inster object and i see a lot of options ( adobe, word, )  is this an MS equation ?

Comment: @PBennett - updated my OP, let me know if this helps!